# Finding feasible solution of inequalities in math software

Tags: inequality, matlab, mathematica

I have a Math problem where I have some true statements, and I want to know if there is a feasible solution to an equation.  I would like to know how to do that in either Matlab or Mathematica.

The true statements are:

```
0 < a, b, c, d, e
a, b, c integers
a < b < c
d*b + e*b > e * c
```

I want to know that, if given those conditions, it is possible to find values for `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, such that the following inequality holds:

```
d*a > d*b +e*b - e*c
```

If you know a way to tackle this analytically, it would also be valuable.